# React InputForm Value With Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-bootstrap

I am a bit new to hooks, and I can't seem to get my FormControl value to display its value correctly after being changed, the value stays the same on the page.

However I can see that customerNameChanged is being called and customer object is being updated correctly in state, but the value used on the FormControl does not update.

I don't understand why, but I assume it is because the value is a property of an object. Can anyone explain further?

```
export default function Customer(props) {

    const { match } = props;
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [customer, setCustomer] = useState({});
    const [params] = useState(match.params);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function load() {
            const customer = await loadCustomer(params.id);
            setCustomer(customer.data);

            setLoading(false);
        }
        load();
    }, [])

    function customerNameChanged(event) {
        customer.name = event.target.value;
        setCustomer(customer);
    }

    function renderCustomer() {
        return (<div>
            <InputGroup className="mb-3">
                <InputGroup.Prepend>
                    <InputGroup.Text id="basic-addon1">Name</InputGroup.Text>
                </InputGroup.Prepend>
                <FormControl
                    placeholder="Name"
                    aria-label="CustomerName"
                    aria-describedby="basic-addon1"
                    value={customer.name}
                    onChange={customerNameChanged}
                />
            </InputGroup>
        </div>)
    }

    return (<Card><LoadedContent isLoading={loading} content={renderCustomer()} /></Card>)
}
```

Comment: Can you try checking the value of `event.target.value` in `customerNameChanged`? I'm thinking you might be setting it to a `String` instead of an `Object`.

Comment: You shouldn't need to set the customer name to e.target.value and also call set customer. Even with this though, I'm not 100% sure why what you have shouldn't work. Try removing the customer.name line, and replace setCustomer with `setCustomer(customer => {...customer, name: e.target.value})`

Comment: @Ayushya It is definitely a string.

Comment: @Ibz I put a console.log(customer); line after setCustomer and I can see customer name has changed correctly, so I don't think there is anything wrong with updating the customer object.

Comment: @ChristopherTownsend , I would still suggest giving what I said a try. Hooks aren't quite as straight forward as you might expect.

Comment: @Ibz that worked! Thanks!

Comment: @ChristopherTownsend no worries! Yeah like I said, although hooks look really quite simple on the surface, there's quite a lot going on in the background. The main things to remember is that whether or not a component re-renders is dependent on equality values. As you were essentially setting customer to the same object, the component didn't know to refresh. Our solution creates a new customer object, which has a different reference to the original object hence causing a re-render. If anything else comes up or needs explaining, let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the solution, thanks to @Ibz for the answer!

```
function customerNameChanged(event) {
    setCustomer({ ...customer, name: event.target.value });
}
```